# Why do I get "No such file or directory found" for my grunt/Sass/Ruby code?

Tags: ruby, sass, gruntjs

I created a grunt file to watch and compile my Sass code and JavaScript on save.  While this works beautifully on the JavaScript portion, somewhere it is failing when compiling the Sass and can not find the source file to use even if the directory and file name are correctly given.

The error I receive is:

```
Running 'sass:dist' <sass> task 
Errno:ENOENT No such file or directory - Content/site.scss
```

This is my Grunt file:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  var jsSource = [
    'Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js',
    'Scripts/jquery.cookie.js',
    'Scripts/respond.1.1.0.js',
    'Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js',
    'Scripts/script-compensation.js',
    'Scripts/webtrends.load.js'
  ];
  var jsDebug = 'scripts/site.js';
  var jsRelease = 'scripts/site.min.js';
  var jsWatchFiles = ['Scripts/script-compensation.js'];
  var cssWatchFiles = ['Content/*.scss'];
  var scssSource = ['Content/site.scss'];

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({

    concat: {
      application: {
        src: jsSource,
        dest: jsDebug
      }
    },

    uglify: {
      options: {
        report: 'min'
      },
      application: {
        src: ['<%= concat.application.dest %>'],
        dest: jsRelease
      }
    },

   sass: {
        options: {
          style: 'expanded'
        },
        dist: {
            files: {
                'Content/site.css': scssSource
            }
        }
    },

    watch: {
      js: {
        files: jsWatchFiles,
        tasks: ['concat']
      },

      css: {
          files: cssWatchFiles,
          tasks: ['sass']
      } 
    }

  });


  // These plugins provide necessary tasks.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

 grunt.registerTask("default", function(){
    grunt.log.writeln("grunt workflow task list:");
    grunt.log.writeln("\tgrunt watch - Watch js and scss");
    grunt.log.writeln("\t\tWindows: use 'start /d . grunt watch' for background process");
    grunt.log.writeln("\tgrunt debug - Build the debug files");
    grunt.log.writeln("\tgrunt release - Build the release files");
  });

  grunt.registerTask('debug', ['concat']);
  grunt.registerTask('release', ['concat', 'uglify']);
};
```

I think the error is coming from Ruby itself, but I can not be sure.  Has anyone run across this and if so what can I do to fix?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using File.expand_path() or giving the full path?